# making lists with cassava from csv

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let list = []
    csvData <- BL.readFile "data.csv"
    case decodeByName csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v $ \ p -> putStr $ show (column1 p)
```

I read the data from a CSV file and I managed to print it out. Instead I first want to put the data of the vector `V.forM_ v` in a list and then print it out.

I do not understand the lambda expression `p ->` in the code.

I'm using a custom data type:

```
data Values = Values
    {
        column1 :: !Int,
        column2 :: !Int
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you factor out that lambda expression to a named function:

```
printElement p = putStr $ show (column1 p)
```

Then you could write it as

```
Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v printElement
```

The `\p -> ...` syntax is saying "take an argument called `p` and do `...` with it".  The `V.forM_` function takes a vector and then a monadic function to call on each element of that vector, and in this case `\p -> putStr $ show (column1 p)` is the function given to `forM_`.

If instead you want to make a list of all of the `column1` values, then you could do

```
Right (_, v) -> print $ V.toList $ V.map column1 v
```

The `V.toList $ V.map column1 v` is what you're interested in here, it will calculate `column1` for each of the elements in the vector, then convert that result to a normal Haskell list.

---

To convert your records into lists, you'll want to write your own `toList` function:

```
valuesToList :: Values -> [Int]
valuesToList (Values c1 c2) = [c1, c2]
```

Note that this will only be possible if your record is homogenous, so you could have a `String` or `Float` field mixed in here, since Haskell lists can not contain values of different types.

Then you can simply do

```
Right (_, v) -> print $ V.toList $ V.map valuesToList v
```

Comment: what if I have more columns?

Comment: @letsjak What do you want to do with those columns?

Comment: put each csv line in a list like `[column1, column2,...]`

Comment: @letsjak Can you edit your question with the data type you're trying to read in?  Judging from your use of `column1`, it looks like you're using an accessor on a custom record type that implements `FromNamedRecord`.  Otherwise, you're going to be working with a `Map` or `HashMap`.  With these, you'll basically end up with an unordered container of your data, so you'll probably want a way to convert it to a list in the order you want.  If you're just wanting to read in the data as-is, use the `decode` function instead.